# Mongoose filter using or condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a chat application using nodejs and mongodb. I need need help retrieving messages between two users. The challenge am facing is I don't know how to filter the chats between two users since a user can be a sender or a recipient.

```
const messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content:{type:String, required:true},
    fromUser:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    toUser:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User'},
    messageRead:{type:Boolean, default:false}
},{
    timestamps:true
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [$and](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) and [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operators in a [match](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          fromUser: {
            $in: [
              "user1",
              "user2"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          toUser: {
            $in: [
              "user1",
              "user2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

In mongoose if your model is MessageModel your query must be like this:

```
const messages = await MessageModel.aggregate([...])
```

[Mongodb Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F7WZsR19wiv)

You may need to convert user1 and user2 to ObjectId like this:

```
      fromUser: {
        $in: [
          new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('user1'),
          new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('user2')
        ]
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting the data exactly as you want it. The accepted answer (using `$in` operator) is not as performant as an exact match, and aggregation is a bit overkill for such a basic query.

```
const userA = new ObjectId('user_a_id');
const userB = new ObjectId('user_b_id');
const messages = await MessageModel.find({
  $or: [
    { fromUser: userA, toUser: userB },
    { fromUser: userB, toUser: userA },
  ]
}).exec();
```

Comment: thank you! I've been looking for this solution and it's the only one I could find